# MVC-Mini-Profiler - Web Forms - Can't find /mini-profiler-results

Tags: asp.net, profiling, umbraco, asp.net-profiles

I'm trying to get MVC-mini-profiler to work with webforms.

**NUGET**
I've installed the Nuget package.

```
PM> Install-Package MiniProfiler
```

**Head**
I have this in the head section of my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%= MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
```

**DAL**
  I'm using it inside one function as a POC.  This is not in the Global.asax (I dont know if that's required or not.)

```
profiler = MiniProfiler.Start();

using (profiler.Step("Im doing stuff"))
{
   //do stuff here
}

MvcMiniProfiler.MiniProfiler.Stop();
```

**Result**
It renders a `<div class="profiler-results left"></div>` tag on my page, but it is empty.

If I look at the chrome console I see a 404 trying to find: http://example.com/mini-profiler-results?id=339d84a7-3898-429f-974b-64038462d59a&popup=1

**Question**
Am I missing a step to get the /mini-profiler-results link to work?

**Answer**
The response I marked as answer led me to think that it had nothing to do with my configuration (which is true).  I am using Umbraco 4.7.0.  I had to add "~/mini-profiler-results" to umbracoReservedUrls and umbracoReservedPaths in my web.config.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087101/miniprofiler-for-asp-net-web-site

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following page worked just great for me after installing the NuGet package:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcMiniProfiler" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading" %>

<script type="text/c#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MiniProfiler.Start();
        using (MiniProfiler.Current.Step("I'm doing stuff"))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(300);
        }
        MiniProfiler.Stop();
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <%= MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes() %>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: quick update for the latest version, the namespace has changed from "MvcMiniProfiler" to "StackExchange.Profiling", so just change the second line, and it's all good.....